# nix-build fails to build plutus or plutus-playground server/client with error: reading from file: Is a directory

Tags: plutus, plutus-pioneer-program, plutus-playground, plutus-starter

I'm attempting to finish the setup for plutus pioneers cohort3 on wsl2 (Windows 10) with Ubunutu 20.04

Nix version: 2.5.1

I cloned the plutus-apps repo (and previously tried the plutus repo before instructions to change to plutus-apps)

I have followed several different sets of instructions, reinstalled nix, tried removing and recloning the repo, and various other potential fixes, but always get to the same error:

```
/plutus-apps$ nix-build -A plutus-playground.server --show-trace
error: reading from file: Is a directory

       … while evaluating 'gitignoreToRegexes'

       at /nix/store/wqw9whwr9qkhhzjs81cv38y4ssspd0sw-source/rules.nix:86:24:

           85|   # string -> [[regex bool]]
           86|   gitignoreToRegexes = gitignore:
             |                        ^
           87|     assert throwIfOldNix;

       … from call site

       at /nix/store/wqw9whwr9qkhhzjs81cv38y4ssspd0sw-source/rules.nix:151:47:

          150|
          151|   gitignoreFilter = ign: root: filterPattern (gitignoreToRegexes ign) root;
             |                                               ^
          152| }

       … while evaluating 'reverseList'

       at /nix/store/kawxd91ly09hlyqprqs7yn650s3cfvf6-source/lib/lists.nix:393:17:

          392|   */
          393|   reverseList = xs:
             |                 ^
          394|     let l = length xs; in genList (n: elemAt xs (l - n - 1)) l;

       … from call site

       at /nix/store/wqw9whwr9qkhhzjs81cv38y4ssspd0sw-source/rules.nix:46:18:

           45|       # Last item has the last say; might as well start there
           46|       reversed = reverseList patterns;
             |                  ^
           47|

       … while evaluating anonymous lambda

       at /nix/store/wqw9whwr9qkhhzjs81cv38y4ssspd0sw-source/rules.nix:56:13:

           55|     in
           56|       name: _type:
             |             ^
           57|         let

       … from call site

       at /nix/store/wqw9whwr9qkhhzjs81cv38y4ssspd0sw-source/rules.nix:75:14:

           74|     let ra = pa name type;
           75|         rb = pb name type;
             |              ^
           76|     in if rb != null

       … while evaluating 'mergePattern'

       at /nix/store/wqw9whwr9qkhhzjs81cv38y4ssspd0sw-source/rules.nix:73:33:

           72|   # may override the result of preceding ones.
           73|   mergePattern = pa: pb: (name: type:
             |                                 ^
           74|     let ra = pa name type;

       … from call site

       at /nix/store/wqw9whwr9qkhhzjs81cv38y4ssspd0sw-source/rules.nix:74:14:

           73|   mergePattern = pa: pb: (name: type:
           74|     let ra = pa name type;
             |              ^
           75|         rb = pb name type;

       … while evaluating 'mergePattern'

       at /nix/store/wqw9whwr9qkhhzjs81cv38y4ssspd0sw-source/rules.nix:73:33:

           72|   # may override the result of preceding ones.
           73|   mergePattern = pa: pb: (name: type:
             |                                 ^
           74|     let ra = pa name type;

       … from call site

       at /nix/store/wqw9whwr9qkhhzjs81cv38y4ssspd0sw-source/rules.nix:36:18:

           35|       let
           36|         result = r (toString path) type;
             |                  ^
           37|       in

       … while evaluating 'runFilterPattern'

       at /nix/store/wqw9whwr9qkhhzjs81cv38y4ssspd0sw-source/rules.nix:34:14:

           33|   runFilterPattern =
           34|     r: path: type:
             |              ^
           35|       let

       … from call site

       at /nix/store/wqw9whwr9qkhhzjs81cv38y4ssspd0sw-source/find-files.nix:84:32:

           83|                               type == nodeTypes.directory &&
           84|                               (parse-gitignore.runFilterPattern currentPatterns (dir + "/${name}") type)
             |                                ^
           85|                            ) nodes;

       … while evaluating anonymous lambda

       at /nix/store/wqw9whwr9qkhhzjs81cv38y4ssspd0sw-source/find-files.nix:82:35:

           81|     let nodes = readDir dir;
           82|         dirs = filterAttrs (name: type:
             |                                   ^
           83|                               type == nodeTypes.directory &&

       … from call site

       at /nix/store/kawxd91ly09hlyqprqs7yn650s3cfvf6-source/lib/attrsets.nix:125:62:

          124|   filterAttrs = pred: set:
          125|     listToAttrs (concatMap (name: let v = set.${name}; in if pred name v then [(nameValuePair name v)] else []) (attrNames set));
             |                                                              ^
          126|

       … while evaluating anonymous lambda

       at /nix/store/kawxd91ly09hlyqprqs7yn650s3cfvf6-source/lib/attrsets.nix:125:29:

          124|   filterAttrs = pred: set:
          125|     listToAttrs (concatMap (name: let v = set.${name}; in if pred name v then [(nameValuePair name v)] else []) (attrNames set));
             |                             ^
          126|

       … from call site

       at /nix/store/kawxd91ly09hlyqprqs7yn650s3cfvf6-source/lib/attrsets.nix:125:18:

          124|   filterAttrs = pred: set:
          125|     listToAttrs (concatMap (name: let v = set.${name}; in if pred name v then [(nameValuePair name v)] else []) (attrNames set));
             |                  ^
          126|

       … while evaluating 'filterAttrs'

       at /nix/store/kawxd91ly09hlyqprqs7yn650s3cfvf6-source/lib/attrsets.nix:124:23:

          123|   */
          124|   filterAttrs = pred: set:
             |                       ^
          125|     listToAttrs (concatMap (name: let v = set.${name}; in if pred name v then [(nameValuePair name v)] else []) (attrNames set));

       … from call site

       at /nix/store/wqw9whwr9qkhhzjs81cv38y4ssspd0sw-source/find-files.nix:82:16:

           81|     let nodes = readDir dir;
           82|         dirs = filterAttrs (name: type:
             |                ^
           83|                               type == nodeTypes.directory &&

       … while evaluating 'findDescendantPatternsTree'

       at /nix/store/wqw9whwr9qkhhzjs81cv38y4ssspd0sw-source/find-files.nix:80:49:

           79|   # currentPatterns.
           80|   findDescendantPatternsTree = currentPatterns: dir:
             |                                                 ^
           81|     let nodes = readDir dir;

       … from call site

       at /nix/store/wqw9whwr9qkhhzjs81cv38y4ssspd0sw-source/find-files.nix:70:7:

           69|     in
           70|       findDescendantPatternsTree startingPatterns dir;
             |       ^
           71|

       … while evaluating 'findPatternsTree'

       at /nix/store/wqw9whwr9qkhhzjs81cv38y4ssspd0sw-source/find-files.nix:60:22:

           59|    */
           60|   findPatternsTree = dir:
             |                      ^
           61|     let

       … from call site

       at /nix/store/wqw9whwr9qkhhzjs81cv38y4ssspd0sw-source/find-files.nix:22:24:

           21|     let
           22|       patternsBelowP = findPatternsTree basePath;
             |                        ^
           23|       basePathStr = toString basePath;

       … while evaluating 'getPatterns'

       at /nix/store/wqw9whwr9qkhhzjs81cv38y4ssspd0sw-source/find-files.nix:34:18:

           33|   getPatterns =
           34|     patternTree: pathElems:
             |                  ^
           35|       if length pathElems == 0

       … from call site

       at /nix/store/wqw9whwr9qkhhzjs81cv38y4ssspd0sw-source/find-files.nix:39:14:

           38|         if hd == "" || hd == "."
           39|         then getPatterns patternTree (tail pathElems)
             |              ^
           40|         else

       … while evaluating 'getPatterns'

       at /nix/store/wqw9whwr9qkhhzjs81cv38y4ssspd0sw-source/find-files.nix:34:18:

           33|   getPatterns =
           34|     patternTree: pathElems:
             |                  ^
           35|       if length pathElems == 0

       … from call site

       at /nix/store/wqw9whwr9qkhhzjs81cv38y4ssspd0sw-source/find-files.nix:28:59:

           27|         localDirPathElements = splitString "/" localDirPath;
           28|         patternResult = parse-gitignore.runFilterPattern (getPatterns patternsBelowP localDirPathElements)."/patterns" path type;
             |                                                           ^
           29|         nonempty = any (nodeName: gitignoreFilter (basePath + "/${nodeName}") != false)

       … while evaluating 'runFilterPattern'

       at /nix/store/wqw9whwr9qkhhzjs81cv38y4ssspd0sw-source/rules.nix:34:14:

           33|   runFilterPattern =
           34|     r: path: type:
             |              ^
           35|       let

       … from call site

       at /nix/store/wqw9whwr9qkhhzjs81cv38y4ssspd0sw-source/find-files.nix:28:25:

           27|         localDirPathElements = splitString "/" localDirPath;
           28|         patternResult = parse-gitignore.runFilterPattern (getPatterns patternsBelowP localDirPathElements)."/patterns" path type;
             |                         ^
           29|         nonempty = any (nodeName: gitignoreFilter (basePath + "/${nodeName}") != false)

       … while evaluating anonymous lambda

       at /nix/store/wqw9whwr9qkhhzjs81cv38y4ssspd0sw-source/find-files.nix:25:13:

           24|     in
           25|       path: type: let
             |             ^
           26|         localDirPath = removePrefix basePathStr (toString (dirOf path));

       … from call site

       at /nix/store/8n76c1c3nz2wl6dzxmxdz2y5xrx70flw-source/lib/clean-source-with.nix:75:17:

           74|            ((includeSiblings || lib.strings.hasPrefix (origSrcSubDir + "/") path)
           75|              && filter path type # Use the filter function to decide if we need it
             |                 ^
           76|            )

       … while evaluating 'filter''

       at /nix/store/8n76c1c3nz2wl6dzxmxdz2y5xrx70flw-source/lib/clean-source-with.nix:67:23:

           66|         else path: type: true;
           67|       filter' = path: type:
             |                       ^
           68|         # Respect the parent filter

       … from call site

       at /nix/store/8n76c1c3nz2wl6dzxmxdz2y5xrx70flw-source/lib/clean-source-with.nix:109:18:

          108|       filter = filter';
          109|       outPath = (builtins.path { filter = filter'; path = origSrc; name = name'; }) + origSubDir;
             |                  ^
          110|       _isLibCleanSourceWithEx = true;

       … while adding path '/home/toddy/Cardano-all-stuff/plutus-apps'

       at /nix/store/8n76c1c3nz2wl6dzxmxdz2y5xrx70flw-source/lib/clean-source-with.nix:109:18:

          108|       filter = filter';
          109|       outPath = (builtins.path { filter = filter'; path = origSrc; name = name'; }) + origSubDir;
             |                  ^
          110|       _isLibCleanSourceWithEx = true;

       … while evaluating 'check'

       at /nix/store/kawxd91ly09hlyqprqs7yn650s3cfvf6-source/lib/types.nix:356:15:

          355|       name = "path";
          356|       check = x: isCoercibleToString x && builtins.substring 0 1 (toString x) == "/";
             |               ^
          357|       merge = mergeEqualOption;

       … from call site

       at /nix/store/kawxd91ly09hlyqprqs7yn650s3cfvf6-source/lib/types.nix:611:18:

          610|       description = "${t1.description} or ${t2.description}";
          611|       check = x: t1.check x || t2.check x;
             |                  ^
          612|       merge = loc: defs:

       … while evaluating 'check'

       at /nix/store/kawxd91ly09hlyqprqs7yn650s3cfvf6-source/lib/types.nix:611:15:

          610|       description = "${t1.description} or ${t2.description}";
          611|       check = x: t1.check x || t2.check x;
             |               ^
          612|       merge = loc: defs:

       … from call site

       at /nix/store/kawxd91ly09hlyqprqs7yn650s3cfvf6-source/lib/modules.nix:559:22:

          558|       if isDefined then
          559|         if all (def: type.check def.value) defsFinal then type.merge loc defsFinal
             |                      ^
          560|         else let allInvalid = filter (def: ! type.check def.value) defsFinal;

       … while evaluating anonymous lambda

       at /nix/store/kawxd91ly09hlyqprqs7yn650s3cfvf6-source/lib/modules.nix:559:17:

          558|       if isDefined then
          559|         if all (def: type.check def.value) defsFinal then type.merge loc defsFinal
             |                 ^
          560|         else let allInvalid = filter (def: ! type.check def.value) defsFinal;

       … from call site


       at /nix/store/kawxd91ly09hlyqprqs7yn650s3cfvf6-source/lib/modules.nix:559:12:

          558|       if isDefined then
          559|         if all (def: type.check def.value) defsFinal then type.merge loc defsFinal
             |            ^
          560|         else let allInvalid = filter (def: ! type.check def.value) defsFinal;

       … while evaluating the attribute 'mergedValue'

       at /nix/store/kawxd91ly09hlyqprqs7yn650s3cfvf6-source/lib/modules.nix:557:5:

          556|     # Type-check the remaining definitions, and merge them. Or throw if no definitions.
          557|     mergedValue =
             |     ^
          558|       if isDefined then

       … while evaluating the option `src':

       … while evaluating the attribute 'value'

       at /nix/store/kawxd91ly09hlyqprqs7yn650s3cfvf6-source/lib/modules.nix:525:9:

          524|     in warnDeprecation opt //
          525|       { value = builtins.addErrorContext "while evaluating the option `${showOption loc}':" value;
             |         ^
          526|         inherit (res.defsFinal') highestPrio;

       … while evaluating anonymous lambda

       at /nix/store/kawxd91ly09hlyqprqs7yn650s3cfvf6-source/lib/modules.nix:140:72:

          139|           # For definitions that have an associated option
          140|           declaredConfig = mapAttrsRecursiveCond (v: ! isOption v) (_: v: v.value) options;
             |                                                                        ^
          141|

       … from call site

       at /nix/store/kawxd91ly09hlyqprqs7yn650s3cfvf6-source/lib/attrsets.nix:301:20:

          300|               then recurse (path ++ [name]) value
          301|               else f (path ++ [name]) value;
             |                    ^
          302|         in mapAttrs g set;

       … while evaluating 'g'

       at /nix/store/kawxd91ly09hlyqprqs7yn650s3cfvf6-source/lib/attrsets.nix:298:19:

          297|           g =
          298|             name: value:
             |                   ^
          299|             if isAttrs value && cond value

       … from call site

       … while evaluating 'readIfExists'

       at /nix/store/8n76c1c3nz2wl6dzxmxdz2y5xrx70flw-source/modules/cabal-project.nix:4:25:

            3| with types;
            4| let readIfExists = src: fileName:
             |                         ^
            5|       let origSrcDir = src.origSrcSubDir or src;

       … from call site

       at /nix/store/8n76c1c3nz2wl6dzxmxdz2y5xrx70flw-source/modules/cabal-project.nix:49:17:

           48|       type = nullOr str;
           49|       default = readIfExists config.src config.cabalProjectFileName;
             |                 ^
           50|     };

       … while evaluating the attribute 'default'

       at /nix/store/8n76c1c3nz2wl6dzxmxdz2y5xrx70flw-source/modules/cabal-project.nix:49:7:

           48|       type = nullOr str;
           49|       default = readIfExists config.src config.cabalProjectFileName;
             |       ^
           50|     };

       … while evaluating the attribute 'value.content'


       at /nix/store/kawxd91ly09hlyqprqs7yn650s3cfvf6-source/lib/modules.nix:708:14:

          707|     { _type = "override";
          708|       inherit priority content;
             |              ^
          709|     };

       … while evaluating the attribute 'value._type'

       at /nix/store/kawxd91ly09hlyqprqs7yn650s3cfvf6-source/lib/modules.nix:648:73:

          647|       highestPrio = foldl' (prio: def: min (getPrio def) prio) 9999 defs;
          648|       strip = def: if def.value._type or "" == "override" then def // { value = def.value.content; } else def;
             |                                                                         ^
          649|     in {

       … while evaluating anonymous lambda

       at /nix/store/kawxd91ly09hlyqprqs7yn650s3cfvf6-source/lib/modules.nix:547:19:

          546|           # Avoid sorting if we don't have to.
          547|           if any (def: def.value._type or "" == "order") defs''.values
             |                   ^
          548|           then sortProperties defs''.values

       … from call site

       at /nix/store/kawxd91ly09hlyqprqs7yn650s3cfvf6-source/lib/modules.nix:547:14:

          546|           # Avoid sorting if we don't have to.
          547|           if any (def: def.value._type or "" == "order") defs''.values
             |              ^
          548|           then sortProperties defs''.values

       … while evaluating the attribute 'values'

       at /nix/store/kawxd91ly09hlyqprqs7yn650s3cfvf6-source/lib/modules.nix:551:9:

          550|       in {
          551|         values = defs''';
             |         ^
          552|         inherit (defs'') highestPrio;

       … while evaluating the attribute 'mergedValue'

       at /nix/store/kawxd91ly09hlyqprqs7yn650s3cfvf6-source/lib/modules.nix:557:5:

          556|     # Type-check the remaining definitions, and merge them. Or throw if no definitions.
          557|     mergedValue =
             |     ^
          558|       if isDefined then

       … while evaluating the option `cabalProject':

       … while evaluating the attribute 'value'

       at /nix/store/kawxd91ly09hlyqprqs7yn650s3cfvf6-source/lib/modules.nix:525:9:

          524|     in warnDeprecation opt //
          525|       { value = builtins.addErrorContext "while evaluating the option `${showOption loc}':" value;
             |         ^
          526|         inherit (res.defsFinal') highestPrio;

       … while evaluating anonymous lambda

       at /nix/store/kawxd91ly09hlyqprqs7yn650s3cfvf6-source/lib/modules.nix:140:72:

          139|           # For definitions that have an associated option
          140|           declaredConfig = mapAttrsRecursiveCond (v: ! isOption v) (_: v: v.value) options;
             |                                                                        ^
          141|

       … from call site

       at /nix/store/kawxd91ly09hlyqprqs7yn650s3cfvf6-source/lib/attrsets.nix:301:20:

          300|               then recurse (path ++ [name]) value
          301|               else f (path ++ [name]) value;
             |                    ^
          302|         in mapAttrs g set;

       … while evaluating 'g'

       at /nix/store/kawxd91ly09hlyqprqs7yn650s3cfvf6-source/lib/attrsets.nix:298:19:

          297|           g =
          298|             name: value:
             |                   ^
          299|             if isAttrs value && cond value

       … from call site

       … while evaluating anonymous lambda

       at /nix/store/8n76c1c3nz2wl6dzxmxdz2y5xrx70flw-source/lib/call-cabal-project-to-nix.nix:9:1:

            8| in
            9| { name          ? src.name or null # optional name for better error messages
             | ^
           10| , src

       … from call site

       at /nix/store/8n76c1c3nz2wl6dzxmxdz2y5xrx70flw-source/overlays/haskell.nix:487:36:

          486|               args = { caller = "cabalProject'"; } // args';
          487|               callProjectResults = callCabalProjectToNix args;
             |                                    ^
          488|               plan-pkgs = importAndFilterProject {

       … while evaluating anonymous lambda

       at /nix/store/8n76c1c3nz2wl6dzxmxdz2y5xrx70flw-source/lib/import-and-filter-project.nix:5:1:

            4| { pkgs, haskellLib }:
            5| { projectNix, sourceRepos, src }:
             | ^
            6| let

       … from call site

       at /nix/store/8n76c1c3nz2wl6dzxmxdz2y5xrx70flw-source/overlays/haskell.nix:488:27:

          487|               callProjectResults = callCabalProjectToNix args;
          488|               plan-pkgs = importAndFilterProject {
             |                           ^
          489|                 inherit (callProjectResults) projectNix sourceRepos src;

       … while evaluating the attribute 'hsPkgs'

       at /nix/store/8n76c1c3nz2wl6dzxmxdz2y5xrx70flw-source/overlays/haskell.nix:510:43:

          509|               project = addProjectAndPackageAttrs rec {
          510|                   inherit (pkg-set.config) hsPkgs;
             |                                           ^
          511|                   inherit pkg-set;

       … while evaluating the attribute 'hsPkgs'

       at /nix/store/8n76c1c3nz2wl6dzxmxdz2y5xrx70flw-source/overlays/haskell.nix:533:15:

          532|               # Haskell packages
          533|               hsPkgs = final.lib.mapAttrs (packageName: package':
             |               ^
          534|                 if package' == null

       … while evaluating the attribute 'packages.plutus-playground-server.components.exes.plutus-playground-server'

       at /home/toddy/Cardano-all-stuff/plutus-apps/nix/pkgs/haskell/default.nix:63:10:

           62| rec {
           63|   inherit index-state compiler-nix-name project projectAllHaddock projectPackages projectPackagesAllHaddock packages;
             |          ^
           64|   inherit extraPackages;

       … while evaluating the attribute 'server'

       at /home/toddy/Cardano-all-stuff/plutus-apps/plutus-playground-client/default.nix:87:3:

           86|   inherit client generate-purescript start-backend;
           87|   server = playground-exe;
             |   ^
           88| }
```

I've included the entire trace for completeness.  I get the same error when running:

```
nix build -f default.nix plutus.haskell.packages.plutus-core.components.library --extra-experimental-features nix-command --show-trace
```

Comment: Welcome to Cardano SE! As a new user be sure to take the [Tour].

Answer (score 0):

did you

2. Go to the latest commit of the repository, before doing nix-build:

> git checkout 41149926c108c71831cfe8d244c83b0ee4bf5c8a

this gives you a message that you are at HEAD ****f5c8a

Going to this commit helped me, I had build errors too

Comment: Welcome to Cardano SE! As a new user be sure to take the [Tour].

Comment: Hey, yeah I was at that commit.  I just started over with a fresh VM and after getting it working, did some minor additional setup, and it broke again in the same way.  I have no idea why my custom setup would be impacting the repo like this, but that's the only thing that makes sense

Comment: No your should not be the issue. I have the same setup: wsl2+ Ubuntu and it runs great